# Выборка из нескольких таблиц SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Проблема сложилась такая:
Есть две таблицы, click | conversion, в них есть даты создания записей.
Вывожу информацию, к примеру сколько за час было кликов и конверсий, к таблице click джойню таблицу conversion, и вроде бы все не чего, но вот столкнулся с проблемой, что если за определенный промежуток времени конверсии были, а кликов - нет, то запрос не чего не выводит так как он не может связать эти таблицы.
Направьте пожалуйста в какую сторону копнуть в таком случае

Comment: Копнуть  надо в сторону `outer join`.

Comment: А если не было ни того, ни другого - нужны два нуля? или такую запись можно не выводить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Т.к. в MySQL нет `full join`, т.к. её посчитали избыточной, попробуйте так:

```
select date,
  count(clicks) as clicks_cnt,
  count(conversions) as conversions_cnt
from
   (select date, id as clicks, null as conversions
    from click
    union all
    select date, null as clicks, id as conversions
    from conversion) t
group by date
```

Comment: Лучше UNION ALL - зачем нужна лишняя, причём бессмысленная, сортировка?

Comment: спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать